# Video.js, Infinite Scroll, and Masonry: Videos do not load on newly loaded content

Tags: jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll, video.js

I am using infinite-scroll.js, video.js, and masonry.js.  The first page loads correctly (i.e., images of videos load within video players within "pintrest-style" boxes. However, as the user scrolls down, only the pintrest-style" boxes load with empty video players (i.e., no images and videos do not play). I think I should be reinitializing video.js somehow, but I can't figure out how to do so properly with multiple videos.  My js code is below. How would I get the newly loaded boxes to load video players?

```
  $container.infinitescroll({
debug: false,
//extraScrollPx: 40,
bufferPx: 40,
navSelector  : '#navigation',    // selector for the paged navigation 
nextSelector : '#navigation a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
itemSelector : '.masonry_object',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
loading: {
    finishedMsg: null,
    img: "img/loader.gif",
    msg: null,
    msgText: " ",
    speed: 'fast',
  }
},
// trigger Masonry as a callback
function( newElements ) {
  // hide new items while they are loading
  var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({display:"none"},{ opacity: 0 });
  // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
  $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
    // show elems now they're ready

    $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
    $newElems.show().delay(1000).animate({ opacity: 1 },1000);
    $newElems.videojs("example_video_number", { "controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "auto" });
  });
}
```

);

Comment: are you adding a video tag with the id of "example_video_number" when you are creating the new masonry items?  Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I am adding such an id tag.  and it doesn't look like the console is firing any errors...